# Why isn't an import needed for a class referred to by another class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm starting the Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl and encountered something unclear to me almost immediately, coming from familiarity with JS/python/java/etc.

After using the scaffolding generator to create a Users resource, you have a controller that starts off like so in `users_controller.rb`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
```

It's referring to the User model in `models/user.rb`, I believe, which this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Simple enough! The thing that I can't quite follow is how the controller is able to refer to `User.all` without importing the class. What mechanism is making `User` available to the other file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby does not have a module system. There is no such thing as `import`. Any code that is loaded in the current process is always available.

Comment: if you would like to dig i would suggest https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Comment: My knee-jerk response is "but if I create two files, class1.rb and class2.rb, no rails involved, how can class1 access class2?" There *has* to be an import system, otherwise we'd be implying any rb file can access any other rb file anywhere on the system without being given any information about where to find it. That of course doesn't make sense. And I see there is a `require` keyword, so I'm just trying to reconcile that with this answer here.

Comment: @temporary_user_name: There is no `require` keyword in Ruby. I don't know where you found this information, but if I were you, I would make sure to stay away from that tutorial as far as I possibly can! There *is* a method named `Kernel#require`, but that is *not* part of a module system, for the simple reason that Ruby *does not have* a module system. All that `require` does is simply *run* the code. It is actually just a wrapper around the `Kernel#load` method. Obviously, you need to run your code, but there is no module you need to import, because *Ruby has no module system*.

Comment: Ruby *does* have a language feature called `module`, but that has nothing to do with a module system. Modules in Ruby can act as *namespaces*, as *mixins*, or both, but they are *not* modules in the sense that the word is commonly understood, because Ruby *does not have a module system*.